# Town Hall meeting

Tags: discussion, town-hall-meeting

cstheory is around a year old and around 6 months has passed since the moderator elections. What do you think about having a Town Hall meeting on cstheory chat? We can discuss anything related to cstheory, e.g. how things are going, how we can improve things, etc.

Update: here are the links to [part I](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47/conversation/cstheory-town-hall-i) (Jul 14 2011, 0600-0700 UTC) and [part II](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47/conversation/cstheory-town-hall-ii-jul-14-2011) (Jul 14 2011, 1700-1800 UTC) of the town hall meeting

Comment: Sounds good to me.

Comment: Certainly sounds like a good plan.

Comment: definitely a good idea. we should fix maybe a couple of different times for the chat, depending on the time zone ?

Comment: Wow, time files! It's really a good idea. We have some new heavy users in our community. Maybe we can have them share the ideas of improving the site.

Comment: Completely off topic: I'd like to say that I think the three elected moderators have been doing a fantastic job.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, I think we need to make an announce a few days before the meeting so people can schedule their program. How about these:

WHAT: cstheory Town Hall meeting

WHERE: cstheory chat

WHEN: Thursday, July 14, 2011

- 6-7 GMT   (for Asia)
- 17-18 GMT (for Europe and Americas)

You can register for the event so you get a reminder as the event approaches:  http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/47/theoretical-computer-science?tab=schedule

---

**EDIT 1**: I fixed the time for Europe/Americas

**EDIT 2**: moved the date to Thursday, July 14

Comment: the Asia time works for me, but the 15-16 GMT time is 7-8 in the morning in the MT zone, so I'm unlikely to be on then :). Which is fine: we don't all have to be on at the same time.

Comment: @Suresh, my mistake. I was trying to set it such that it will start in 9AM in the Pacific Time. Let me fix it.

Comment: I can try. 17-18 GMT puts it at around dinner time on a (particularly special) friday evening ... we'll see.

Comment: @Dave, I thought that Friday would be easier for people who need to wake up the next day, but since now we are having two we can move it to say Thursday, June 14 if that helps. Would it be better if it is on Thursday?

Comment: Thursday might be better, but I'll possibly have international guests who I'll need to entertain/schmooze with.

Comment: @Dave, OK, I will change it to Thursday and hopefully your guests will be tired enough to want to go to bed early and you can join us. :)

Comment: Again it's going to be at dinner time. But perhaps the guests will eat alone (or return to Portugal).

Comment: Time to promote the town hall ?

Comment: @Suresh, yes. How about a system message like "[cstheory Town Hall meeting](http://meta.cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/1173/) in [cstheory chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/) on Thursday, July 14, 6-7GMT or 17-18GMT"? I think we may also want to send an email to the high-rep cstheory users.

Comment: I'll also mention it in other places, for anyone interested.

Answer (score 3):

Let's first decide some dates/times, and then we can use system messages/blogs etc to promote it.

Comment: How about a day in the first week of July?

Comment: that can work. not too close to SODA deadline though :) (jul 12)

Comment: How about 15-16 GMT Friday, July 1st? (9AM-10AM in the west coast, noon-1 PM in the east coast, and afternoon/evening in the Europe/Middle East/South Asia, past midnight in China/Japan/East Asia)?

Comment: It is difficult to get a time that would be suitable both for US/Canada west coast and China because they are 12 hours apart, so we are going to miss some part in Europe if we try to have it in the morning in China and cover West coast. Having it on Friday night would probably help those in China/Japan who want be staying awake past midnight for the meeting and might not be able to wake up the next morning. If anyone has a better time/date post it and we can then count the upvotes on comments to see which one is more popular.

Comment: We might need to do it in batches ?

Comment: Seems a good idea, we can schedule another one for the users in Asia.