# Agenda for town hall meeting

Tags: discussion, town-hall-meeting

Now that we have a [town hall meeting](https://cstheory.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1173/town-hall-meeting) set up, I'm wondering if we should formulate a few topics of interest, so that we have something to start the discussions rolling ? List one topic per answer, and we can vote on them.

Comment: Register [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/47/theoretical-computer-science?tab=schedule) to receive a reminder for the meetings.

Answer (score 9):

Who is going to write what for the blog?

Answer (score 6):

Are we comfortable with the filtering on questions (level/quality) ?

Answer (score 6):

Developments on the blog (it's up and running) :)

Answer (score 5):

Evaluation of community moderator performance.

Answer (score 4):

Down-voting without commenting and general etiquette.

Comment: Upvoted with the following comment: I almost always comment when I downvote (or more often, vote to close).  It has generated some pretty angry responses, and I think I am moderately diplomatic. I think a lot of people don't comment because they don't want the static, and I'm not sure how to change that.

Comment: That certainly happens frequently too.

Comment: I must admit I sometimes downvote without comment and simply +1 an existing reason that I agree with. Is this bad form?

Comment: If there's a reason already, it's fine. There is a lot of down-voting with no reason given at all.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe a mentoring system for new users?

Comment: Could you elaborate on this?

Answer (score 2):

Have active users become less involved in managing cstheory?

Answer (score 1):

Our relation with other SE sites whose scope intersects with ours

Comment: Particularly [Cryptography](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/15811/cryptography), see [this](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/15811/cryptography), [this](http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/questions/1557/scope-of-cryptography-proposal-overlaps-with-other-existing-sites), and [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2565/relation-to-cryptography-se).